# Mongdb hadoop integration for faster data processing

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

Mongodb can be integrated with hadoop to do the faster data processing but during this course of integration(MongoDB->Hadoop), data gets transferred from mongodb to hadoop. 
Question here is,

1.Cost of data transfer from mongodb to hadoop is it not costlier than actual data processing in mongodb ?

2.Is data transfer (MongoDB->Hadoop) is it a one time activity ?, if yes, how is later updates to mongodb will be reflected in hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

To meet the "Single Source of truth" principle you should try to not 'copy' the data and you shouldn't keep it redundant in HDFS.

To avoid that the Mongo-Hadoop connector allows you to query Mongodb directly instead of the local HDFS. This has of course the **drawback** that your production database gets more load.
The alternative it to query against your mongodb bson dumps.

**To your questions:**

to 1.:
If the Hadoop nodes are "near" to the mongo nodes it isn't to much overhead. When you use Hadoops map reduce it enables you to use more features like HIVE, PIG, ... which you can't use on Mongos Map Reduce.
And it enables you to scale the "calculation power" on demaned without touching your database (all hadoop nodes will be used. On MongoDB you need to take care about the shard key).

to 2.:
You do it over and over again. (Expected you are using capped collection and you configured an Stream to process it. But i guess you aren't using those).

You should read about the `Lambda Architecture` in the Big Data Book http://www.manning.com/marz/ .
They define really nice why you combine smth. like MongoDB and Hadoop.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Now I am clear that, we need to push data to Hadoop to have it processed.

Could you please give me couple of scenarios when we should go for this kind of processing (Hadoop -> MongoDB Integration)